# How to contribute to very outdated pages in Ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-wiki

I was looking for hardware pages in the Ubuntu Wiki like for example:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsMultimediaWebCamerasGenius

And the last time several of those were tested was before Star Wars was invented. So how can I help in pages like those to update the webcams there and add new ones.

In this example is webcams but the intention is not just webcams but other hardware.

Since this is **THE** Wiki for Ubuntu I would like to help to keep it updated with new hardware since I get to see a lot of hardware on a daily basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q: "How to contribute to very outdated wiki pages in Ubuntu"**

They are wiki pages:

[image]

(1) Log in

Quote#1: "If you do not have an account yet, you can still log in with your OpenID and create one during login."

Quote#2: "Please note that if you've registered with Launchpad you can use your existing Launchpad credentials to log in. "

(2) Edit

[image]

Comment: It will be great if you add to your question a link to the wiki guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WikiGuide. The part about communication with other editors is probably quite important.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new website for hardware-related compatibility information: [Ubuntu Friendly](http://friendly.ubuntu.com/).

There was a class titled *‟Is your system Ubuntu Friendly? Contributing to the community hardware testing program”* by Daniel Manrique (roadmr) on 10/18/2011. You can read the log [here](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2011/10/18/%23ubuntu-classroom.html#t16:01).

If you are planning to contribute, you should also consider running the tests and sending in the results.

Comment: +1 Because that is the smart way to go. A database of all PCs added by the community that will show all users what hardware is supported by Ubuntu.

Comment: Tried to upload my hardware and there was this option in the webpage https://launchpad.net/+hwdb/+submit called Unique Submission Key. Did not know what that was.

Comment: Did you use the procedure showcased on page http://friendly.ubuntu.com/participate/? As far as I understand, the Launchpad page tells that the results should be submitted by the System Testing tool.

Comment: Yes of course but it gave an error that is why I ended up in that page. If it gives you en error it redirects you to go to that page.

Comment: Just browsed through the bug list (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-friendly/+bugs) but could not find a related bug. It might worth a bug report, although AFAIK the site is still beta and in development, so it could be a temporary inconvenience.

Comment: But anyway thank you for showing me a nice web page for this.

Comment: Daniel M. mailed: My advice to Luis, given his problem, would be to
1 remove the .cache/checkbox directory
2 redo the test run
3 At the "View Report" screen, prior to inputting his e-mail
address and clicking on "Next" to submit his data, confirm that his internet connection is up and running; we've seen a case of one of the test scripts leaving the connection down after it's done.
4 If he still is unable to submit even after the connection has been verified up, please file a bug using "ubuntu-bug checkbox", this should attach all the logfiles needed for us to make a more informed diagnosis.

Comment: Future readers, note that unfortunately the Ubuntu Friendly project didn't work out and is no longer available https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-August/037583.html