# Should I remove very old information from the Ubuntu/community wiki?

Tags: community, ubuntu-wiki

I'm glad to find out that I [should boldy edit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106979) the Ubuntu and community wikis, including [adding new info to old pages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71764), and that there is even a way to [request whole page deletions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42503) where necessary.

However, what if a page contains some useful information, and some just plain old instructions? You know those pages that include stuff about Dapper and Hardy and workarounds that (thankfully) we no longer need, thanks to those same brave souls who went before us.

My instinct is that instructions for non-supported releases should not be on the latest revision of a wiki page. Is there a policy for this? If so, should the old instructions be deleted, archived, or something else? If not, is there a preferred way to separate them out?

Comment: If the information is potentially still useful to someone, don't delete it, just edit the post such that it's clear that the information is out of date, and if possible link to the current information.

Comment: For any newcomers reading this and confused about the dual meanings of "community wiki" in Ubuntu culture, see [Is the “community help wiki” the same as “community wiki” on Ask Ubuntu?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5976/is-the-community-help-wiki-the-same-as-community-wiki-on-ask-ubuntu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jorge did a talk (I guess it was more of an almost-four-minute-long battle cry) about [deleting harmful, old content from the Wiki](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nto7bdqxicI). It makes a lot of sense in some situations.

But I'd personally use it in moderation. If something is just old, it might still apply. If it's just potentially harmful, perhaps improving it with a few warnings might be a better step. I think to qualify for deletion you need to be in the area where its modern-day appeal is really very limited.

You can follow these instructions if you feel something needs to be removed:

- [What team do I need to talk to about deleting a page on help.ubuntu.com?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42503/what-team-do-i-need-to-talk-to-about-deleting-a-page-on-help-ubuntu-com)

Comment: what about pages that include a different (or subtly different) set of instructions for each release, including modern and unsupported releases; should the "unsupported" instructions be removed?

Comment: @d3vid I honestly don't know how protective some people are of the older instructions. You could always open a page discussion or work out who wrote the content it from the history and ping them an email. Age also has something to do with it. I think people are going to care a lot less about 7.10 than 11.10 (both unsupported now). And at the end of the day, the worst that can happen is somebody disagrees and reverts the edit.